# Method in generic class does not return type specified. Why?

Tags: java

The calls to getHighest() and getLowest() below return objects of type Comparable and not T, which is what is wanted. Why, and how can I improve this code so these calls return T instead (so that T's fields and methods are available)?

```
public class HighestLowest<T extends Comparable<T> >  {
  
  private T lowest;
  private T highest;
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    HighestLowest city;
    HighestLowest employee;
    
    City[] cities = new City[3];
    Employee[] employees = new Employee[3];

    city = new HighestLowest<City>(cities);
    employee = new HighestLowest<Employee>(employees);
```

The very next line generates a compiler error:

Error: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getName()
location: interface java.lang.Comparable

I'd like employee.getHighest() to return an Employee (rather than just a Comparable) while still using the generic class/method mechanism, but how?

```
    System.out.println("The oldest employee is: " +
                       employee.getHighest());

  }
  
  public T getLowest() {
    return lowest;
  }
  
  public T getHighest() {
    return highest;
  }
  
  public HighestLowest(T[] of) {
    lowest = lowest(of);
    highest = highest(of);
  }
  
  private T lowest(T[] of) {
    
    T lowest = of[0];
    
    for (T element : of) {
      if (element.compareTo(lowest) < 0) {
        lowest = element;
      }
    }
    
    return lowest;
    
  }
  
  private T highest(T[] of) {
    
    T highest = of[0];
    
    for(T element : of) {
      if (element.compareTo(highest) > 0) {
        highest = element;
      }
    }
    
    return highest;
    
  }
  
}

  class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    // ...
  }
  
  class City implements Comparable<City> {
    // ...
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `employee` variable is declared as raw type `HighestLowest`. The compiler then knows only about its bound which is `Comparable`. Compiler does not know you assigned generic type in runtime.

Solution: declare it as generic type `HighestLowest<Employee>`. The same situation is with `city`. With Java 7+, you can omit repeating generic argument and use `employee = new HighestLowest<>(employees);` (the so called diamond operator)